# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'

Tags: angular, typescript, timer, rxjs

After upgrading my project from Angular 11 to 12, rxjs from 6.6.6 to 7.1.0 and Typescript from 3.9.7 to 4.0.2, I'm getting the following error related to my timer subscription:

> material-input.component.ts:1262:7 - error TS2322: Type 'void' is not
> assignable to type 'Subscription'.
> 1262 **this.onBlurTimerSubscription** = timer(ALLOW_PRIORITY_OPTION_SELECTED_DELAY).subscribe(() => {

The timer is in the onBlur handler below:

```
onBlurTimerSubscription: Subscription;
// Below works to resolve the error. Is it ok?
// onBlurTimerSubscription: Subscription | any; 

onBlur(event: any) {
  this.allowOnChangeEvent = true;
  this.cleanupUnmatchedError();
  this.allowApiCalls = false;
  this.hasFocus = false;
  if (this.autoCompleteDisabled) {
    this.onBlurComplete(event);
  } else {
    /**
     * NOTE - Need to prioritize the `optionSelected` event over blur.
     *        Since the `onChange` event is debounced, if blur fires first
     *        theres a chance it won't execute properly.
     */
    const ALLOW_PRIORITY_OPTION_SELECTED_DELAY = 10 + this.debounceCustomEventDelay;
    this.onBlurTimerSubscription = timer(ALLOW_PRIORITY_OPTION_SELECTED_DELAY).subscribe(() => {
      this.onBlurComplete(event);
    }).add(() => {
      safeUnsubscribe(this.onBlurTimerSubscription);
    });
  }
}
```

This code has worked without issue prior to the updates mentioned above. What steps do I need to take to refactor for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in different ways:

Create a `private` class property of type `Subscription`, store the subscription and in `ngOnDestroy` life cycle hook, unsubscribe to it:

```js
...
export class Component implements OnDestroy {
  private mySub = new Subscription();

  inSomeFunction() {
    // like this or
    this.mySub = timer(ALLOW_PRIORITY_OPTION_SELECTED_DELAY)
     .subscribe(() => this.onBlurComplete(event))

    // like this
    // this works better if you want to handle multiple
    // subscriptions, you just add them
    this.mySub.add(
      timer(ALLOW_PRIORITY_OPTION_SELECTED_DELAY)
       .subscribe(() => this.onBlurComplete(event))
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mySub?.unsubscribe(); // don't forget the ? operator
  }
}
```

Or you can managed the subscription with a `Subject`:

```js
...
export class Component implements OnDestroy {
  private ngSubscription = new Subject();

  inSomeFunction() {
    timer(ALLOW_PRIORITY_OPTION_SELECTED_DELAY)
     .pipe(takeUnitl(this.ngSubscription))
     .subscribe(() => this.onBlurComplete(event))
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ngSubscription.next();
    this.ngSubscription.complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Andres, thanks for this answer. It appears to be resolved with adding "any" to the variable declaration. See update to my question and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @jcoder, You shouldn't use `any`, specifically for this case, you already know the type for your variable `onBlurTimerSubscription` is Subscription, no questions asks... if using `any` solves it, to me feels like you are just hiding the problem. You can give it a try by refactoring your code with any of my approaches posted. If another developer in your team sees this piece of code, they will think that, using `any` for subscription is totally fine and they will start having that bad custom.